# Category support in the explore API endpoint

Tags: foursquare

I want to use categories to explore an area.

If I include a `categoryId` in a call to the explore endpoint, it seems to work! But, this isn’t documented (on an already-experimental API) so I’m not super comfortable using it.

Is there a reason categories aren’t officially supported on this endpoint?

Related, what differences should I see between an explore and a search in an area (with `intent` set to `browse`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The venues/explore endpoint is rapidly, so there will frequently be experimental, undocumented parameters showing up. This does also mean that the behavior of undocumented parameters could change at any time. While we try to avoid making changes that break existing users, please be aware that only documented behavior should be depended on.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the quick response! Are breaking changes like that the kinds of things you’d announce on the [API mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/foursquare-api)?

Comment: Oh, also, what are the big differences between how venues/search (assuming a `browse` intent) and venues/explore work? Trying to figure out if there’s a big enough advantage to using the more-experimental explore. Happy to fork a separate question if you want.

Comment: We try to announce breaking changes whenever possible. You can always reach us at api@foursquare.com as well. venues/explore is used to find venus that the user might be interested in, based off their previous experience and preferences. venues/search with browse intent is used just to find venues close to the point of origin. You should use whichever endpoint fits your needs best